# Scrolling in a single direction: horizontal OR vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I am looking for a way to only scroll horizontal OR vertical inside a html table view while maintaining a header and row that is always visible. Preferably I would like something similar to [this](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/financial) but in pure Javascript without ember or coffeescript. I prefer not to use the ember-table because the rest of my project is not based on ember and I am unfamiliar with it.

So I started out with something similar [here](http://nkmrshn.com/fixedTblHdrLftCol/samples/sample_0_basic.html). It has the benefit of having the header row and column but it scrolls in both the horizontal direction as well as the vertical direction. The difference between this example and the first one is that the addepar table only scrolls in one direction. Which is a more calm user experience.

I have been looking into possible ways to get to where I want. The first part seems to be to check in which direction the user is scrolling. Such a thing can be done with jQuery;

```
var previousScrollvertical = 0,
    previousScrollHorizontal = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){

   var currentVerticalScroll = $(this).scrollTop(),
       currentHorizontalScroll = $(this).scrollLeft();

   if(currentVerticalScroll==previousScrollvertical) {
           if (currentHorizontalScroll > previousScrollHorizontal){
               console.log('Right');
           } else {
              console.log('left');
           }
   } else if(currentHorizontalScroll==previousScrollHorizontal) {
           if (currentVerticalScroll > previousScrollvertical){
               console.log('down');
           } else {
              console.log('up');
           }
   }

   previousScrollHorizontal = currentHorizontalScroll;
   previousScrollvertical =currentVerticalScroll;
});
```

This snippet of code works on any website that has jQuery loaded. You can try it out from the console.

But from here I seem to be stuck. Is it possible to block a scroll direction with jQuery? Is there an easier way to achieve this? Should I be considering a completely different route?

Comment: For clarification: do you want pure javascript or javascript with jQuery? And you could use CSS's `overflow-x:hidden` to stop the other direction when going up and down then allow it again after scrolling has stopped. The same for horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to use jQuery's `scrollTop` or `scrollLeft` to set the scroll of the direction you want to block back to what it was before.

I've created a quick example that shows how one might do that in practice:

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nate/2kmKp/)

```
var $container = $('.table-container');
var $table = $container.find('table');

var previousScroll = [0, 0];
var correction = false;

// Adjust the threshold to a larger number if you'd like it
// to take longer to switch between horizontal and vertical
// scrolling
var threshold = 10;
var direction;
var directionTimeout;

$container.on('scroll', function (event) {
    if (!correction) {
        var element = event.currentTarget,
            $element = $(event.currentTarget),
            x = element.scrollLeft,
            y = element.scrollTop;

        var diff = [
            Math.abs(x - previousScroll[0]),
            Math.abs(y - previousScroll[1])
        ];

        correction = true;

        if (!direction) {
            if (diff[0] > diff[1]) {
                direction = 'horizontal';
            } else if (diff[0] < diff[1]) {
                direction = 'vertical';
            } else {
                direction = 'vertical';
            }
        }

        if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            $element.scrollTop(previousScroll[1]);
            previousScroll = [x, previousScroll[1]];
        } else {
            $element.scrollLeft(previousScroll[0]);
            previousScroll = [previousScroll[0], y];
        }

        clearTimeout(directionTimeout);
        directionTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            direction = null;
        }, threshold);
    } else {
        correction = false;
    }
});
```